# Make single items editable in a list control (C++, MFC)

Tags: c++, xml, mfc, clistctrl

I have a list control (CListCtrl) with two columns (Name, Value). I add entries dynamically from a xml file. Now i want to make the Value-Column editable and subscribe the Edit-Event to write the changes to the xml. How i do this?

My Code now:

```
LVITEM item_value;
item_value.iItem = row; 
item_value.iSubItem = 1;
item_value.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
item_value.pszText = value;
ctrl->SetItem(&item_value);
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29064/CGridListCtrlEx-Grid-Control-Based-on-CListCtrl

Comment: An explanation would have been better.

Comment: In the XML file, the settings are saved. I want that the user an edit this settings in the list control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing an edit control in `CListCtrl` is easier by setting the **LVS_EDITLABELS** style. Use [EditLabel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xxsdd7z.aspx) function to place an edit control for a specific item, and retrieve the new text from edit control using [GetEditControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4x5de10.aspx) function by listening to the notification [**LVN_ENDLABELEDIT**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774814.aspx).